# Multiple text in bootstrap accordion button?

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-5, bootstrap-accordion

I want to create a bootstrap button with a headline which is aligned to the left and some text aligned to the right. It kind of works but I have some problems:
-when minimizing the window the headline is no longer aligned to the left
-at some point in resizing the whole text disappears

```
<div class="accordion-item">
      <h2 class="accordion-header" id="flush-headingThree">
        <button class="py-3 px-2 accordion-button collapsed" type="button" data-bs-toggle="collapse" data-bs-target="#flush-collapseThree" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="flush-collapseThree">
          
            <div class="d-none d-md-block col pe-3"><span class="client">Ducknose</span></div>
          
            <div class="d-block d-sm-none col-auto pe-3"><span class="client">Ducknose</span></div>
        
            <div class="d-none d-md-block col-md-auto">Lorem Ipsum trallala lollo <span class="year">since 2020</span></div>
            <div class="d-block d-sm-none mobile-cat">Lorem Ipsum trallala lollo</div>
         
        </button>
      </h2>
</div>
```

I tried it with the row and container-fluid classes and even without columns at all but there always was some error. (I included just the top part because the rest works fine). As you see in the code I'm a noob and I really don't know what I could try next.. Any help would be appreciated :) Thx in advance!

Comment: You can't use `<div>` inside a button.

Comment: Thx I've changed the button to a div but do you have a suggestion what I could do to solve my other problems? :/

Comment: As far as I understand, you want to change the text of the button on different screen sizes ?